# Making changes to django PWA

Tags: python, django, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I had a all good working website in django and I was running that at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ with `python manage.py runserver` command. Then, I followed all steps at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/make-pwa-of-a-django-project/ link, used their serviceworker.js as is and converted my website to a PWA. The issue is for the first time , the app loaded, I refreshed the page, the app loaded again. Since after, the app does not load but the code of serviceworker.js is shown on my screen every time I run server.

What is going wrong?

Here is the screenshot of the render:

[image: bug]

Moreover, if I try to navigate to any of the app urls such as register, near_park etc, I see the 'Site can't be reached' message on screen and following error in console:

```
serviceworker.js:23  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at serviceworker.js:23
```

And please refer to the serviceworker.js file at the GeeksforGeeks link I provide above to view line 23.

Comment: In your image you're at ```localhost:8000```. Is it the same error if you visit ```127.0.0.1:8000```?

Comment: Yes, very much the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django-simple-pwa just run
`pip install django-simple-pwa`

Then add it to your installed apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'pwa',
]
```

Then follow these documents.

pypi: https://pypi.org/project/django-simple-pwa/

docs: https://django-simple-pwa.readthedocs.io/fa/latest/

Documents are in Persian language but can translate to your local language with google translate I test it there is no translation problems

Answer (score 0):

It wasn’t mentioned in all the tutorials I came across for setting up Django-pwa but it’s very essential for the operation of service in modern browser to switch the request protocol to HTTPS even for local development and testing . As aside this the service worker won’t work as expected .